# Script function not found - Google Sheets issue

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have added a custom menu and script to my google sheets page.  I get an error saying `Script function not found`, followed by showing me my entire script! What have I done wrong?

Error:

```
Script function not found: function mergeDuplicates() { var target = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); var sheet = 
target.getSheetByName("Test"); var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); var 


  dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 2); var data = 
   dataRange.getValues(); var notesByName = {}; for (var i = 0; i < 
   data.length; i++) { var row = data[i]; var curName = row[0]; var curNote 
   = row[1]; if (!curName.trim()) { continue; } if (!notesByName[curName]) 
   { notesByName[curName] = String(curNote); } else { 
    notesByName[curName].concat(curNote); } } var outputData = 
    Object.keys(notesByName).map(function (name) { return [name, 
notesByName[name]]; }); dataRange.clearContent(); var newDataRange = 
sheet.getRange(2, 1, outputData.length, 2); 
newDataRange.setValues(outputData); } For more information, see 
https://developers.google.com/apps-
script/reference/base/menu#addItem(String,String)`
```

Code:

```
function mergeDuplicates()
{
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = target.getSheetByName("Test");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-1, 2);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var notesByName = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
    var row = data[i];
    var curName = row[0];
    var curNote = row[1];
    // empty name
    if (!curName.trim())
    {
      continue;
    }
    // if name found first time, save it to object
    if (!notesByName[curName])
    {
      notesByName[curName] = String(curNote);
    }
    // if duplicate, sum numbers
    else
    {
      notesByName[curName].concat(curNote);
    }
  }
  // prepare data for output
  var outputData = Object.keys(notesByName).map(function(name){
    return [name, notesByName[name]];
  });
  // clear old data
  dataRange.clearContent();
  // write calculated data
  var newDataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, outputData.length, 2);
  newDataRange.setValues(outputData);
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Custom Menu');
  var item = menu.addItem('Merge Duplicates', mergeDuplicates);
  item.addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your menu code look like?  I'm guessing it's a problem with the way you did the addItem in one of your menus.  Perhaps your additem looks like this `addItem('Description','mergeDuplicates()')` rather than this `addItem('Description','mergeDuplicates')`

Comment: My menu code is var item = menu.addItem('Merge Duplicates', mergeDuplicates); => I had seen a few stack questions where that was the issue

Comment: Is that `'mergeDuplicates' or mergeDuplicates`